# An error in the axios (vue.js), namely "id=[object%20Object]"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

As a parameter, I have a "test" id and I pass it to the store, namely index.js. In the console, I have this error -> **users?id=[object%20Object]**. I have already tried -> "this.id.toString()", but it doesn't work. Can somebody help me, please?

user.vue

```
<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
export default {
  data: () => ({
     id: "test",
  }),
  methods: {
    ...mapActions("Test", [
      "GET_USER_BY_ID",
    ]),
    add() {
      this.GET_USER_BY_ID(this.id);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

index.js

```
import axios from '../../plugins/axios'

const actions = {
    GET_USER_BY_ID(userId) { 
    console.log(userId)
        return axios.get(`users?id=${userId}`)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response)
                return response
            })
}

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

Comment: [object Object] is what you get when you try to treat an object as though it's a string (so adding .toString() is the opposite of what you should do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument in actions of `vuex` is a scope object, try like this:

```
const actions = {
  GET_USER_BY_ID(_, userId) {
    ...
  }
}
```